# Инциализация объекта класса в конструкторе как вектора классов

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор, вектор

Всем привет! На англоязычном СО меня не поняли, надеюсь на помощь тут. У меня есть класс `Num` в котором два поля - это вектора объектов классов `One` и `Two`. Мне нужно в конструкторе `Num` с помощью `enum` выбирать один из двух конструкторов и инициализировать их. Мой код:

```
enum typeNum {1, 2};

class One
{
public:
    One(int num){...}
};

class Two
{
public:
    Two(int num){...}
};

class Num
{
public:

    vector <One> one;
    vector <Two> two;

    Num(typeNum type, int num)
    {
        if (type == 1)
       {
            this->one.push_back(One(num));
       }

       if (type == 2)
       {
            this->two.push_back(Two(num));
       }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Num num(1,10);
    num.one[0].someMethodsClassOne();
}
```

Если выполняю данный код выдаёт ошибку ссылки на нулевой указатель:

> `in TEST.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.`

И указывает на содержимое метода `someMethodsClassOne();` где по сути готовятся данные для графики.

Но если в `main` инициализирую `One` и `Two`, напрямую все работает. Дебаг не помогает выявить место ошибки. Можно конечно воспользоваться списком инициализации:

```
 Num(int num) : one(One(num)){}
```

Но у меня вектор и необходим выбор между конструкторами. Как быть? Спасибо!

Comment: Покажите ваш класс `One`, проблема должна быть в нём. Вангую отсутствие копирующего конструктора.

Comment: VladD благодарю, это оказалось отчасти верно. Добавив пустой конструктор копирования запустилось, но графики нет т.к. нет данных. Сделав явный КК с присвоением полей, стало также выдавать ошибку. Я новичёк, укажите пожалуйста где именно в коде  вызывается КК, попробую разобраться. Описать класс One  не смогу, к сожалению, т.к. там много вложенных структур и функций OGL.

Comment: В этой строке `this->one.push_back(One(num));`

Comment: Артём Оконечников Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось проблемы были вызваны из-за некорректной работы деструктора с данными OpenGL. Я не указал в своём вопросе всё описание класса One и Two, и как оказалось зря. У меня были так же поля вертексных, индексных буфферов, массив атрибутов и деструктор который тупо удалял данные после копирования. Это и вызывало ошибку - созданные объекты ссылались на несуществующий буфер:

```
class One
{
public:
vector<glm::vec3> vert;
vector<GLuint3> ind;
GLuint VAO, VBO, EBO;

... 

~One()
{
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &this->VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &this->VBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &this->EBO);
}
```

Решение - удалить деструктор, либо, как указал VladD, организовать правильный конструктор копирования.